# The following code in python "time.time" does nothing

Tags: python, time

I am not yet familiar with Python, I've programmed this code from the documentation I read, but it does nothing, there is no output a all:

```
# -*- coding: latin_1 -*-
import time
from msvcrt import kbhit

Intervall = 1
mytime = int(time.time()) + Intervall
print (time.time ())
print (mytime)
while (kbhit() == False):
    if (int(time.time ()) >= mytime):
# I want this to be done every second:    
        print (int(time.time ()), mytime)
        mytime = int(time.time ()) + Intervall
# I want other things to be done here (outside the if statement)
```

If I comment out this line in the while loop:

```
mytime = int(time.time ()) + Intervall
```

it does what the code says but of course the print statement is executed in every loop run, which is not what I want.

Any help is welcome
(using Python 3.4.1. under Win 7)

Thanks,

Martin.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want.

Comment: The code runs on my machine (also Python 3.4 on Win 7). Is your indention correct (did you copy the code directly from your editor)? I ask because if mytime = int(time.time ()) + Intervall is on the same level is the if statement the code would do what you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Stop coercing the result of `time.time()` to an integer, this may not be the problem, but it is unnecessary.

Stop busy-waiting on the key press, it is a great way to waste CPU. Try instead:

```
while not kbhit():
    print('no kbhit at', time.time())
    time.sleep(1) # do nothing for a second
```

You can also drop `Interval1` and `mytime` as they are unneeded complexity.

Comment: Also, find a better tutorial, that example is poorly written, which probably doesn't speak well for the rest.